# What should I do to stop constantly running components

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

There are 2 languages in my application. The language file is as follows:

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { english } from '../localization/English';
import { german } from '../localization/German';
import { localizationAppSelector } from '../redux/LocalizationAppRedux';


export const useLocalization = () => {

  console.log("xxxxxxx")
  const language = useSelector(localizationAppSelector);

  switch (language[1]) {
    case "en-US":
      return english;
    case "de-DE":
      return german;
    default:
      return english;
  }
}
```

The main page of the application is as follows. Every time I enter a letter into the textInput on the screen, the console.log in the useLocalization method runs and writes xxxxx to the terminal.

```js
import { View, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useLocalization } from '../hooks/useLocalization'


const MainScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [text, setText] = useState("")
    const strings = useLocalization()

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
            <Text>{strings.how_examples}</Text>
            <TextInput
                value={text}
                onChangeText={setText}
                style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}

export default MainScreen
```

In fact, these components in the application are not as simple as I gave above. Costly components run over and over again as each letter is entered. What should I do to prevent this situation? I want this language file to run only when the selected language in redux changes in the language file. I learned that I can use useMemo for this, but when I use it as follows, I get an "Object is not a function" error.

```js
export const useLocalization = React.memo(() => {

  console.log("xxxxxxx")
  const language = useSelector(localizationAppSelector);

  switch (language[1]) {
    case "en-US":
      return english;
    case "de-DE":
      return german;
    default:
      return english;
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you show us `localizationAppSelector`?

Comment: @NicholasTower export const localizationAppSelector = (state) => state.localeApp.language . selector function inside redux

Comment: K, thanks. Just wanted to make sure the selector wasn't creating a new array each time it was called (which would cause unnecessary renders)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're doing two things in one component. This works, but is not a recommended practice. As this [article states](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/when-to-break-up-a-component-into-multiple-components), splitting up components can improve performance.

> Performance would probably suffer: Every state change results in a re-render of the entire application.

In your case, the `useState()` is the culprit. As mentioned in the [React docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#setstate), invoking `setState` (`setText` in your example), will trigger a re-render of the whole component. Because the hook is part of the component, it will also be called again. And the same goes for every other component in `MainScreen`.

The fix is simple.
Split the TextField into its own component. This way, only that component (`ControlledTextInput`) will re-render when its value is updated.

```
function ControlledTextInput() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return <input value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
}

const MainScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const strings = useLocalization()

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "grey" }}>
            <Text>{strings.how_examples}</Text>
            <ControlledTextInput
                style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: In the example you gave, how can I pull the text entered in Text Input to MainScreen?

Comment: You will probably need to use context then. Can u update your initial post with this extra info? Where do you want to want to display this text and why? I'll try to update my answer accordingly.